# How to delete history data from Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Since two months my "Training" section in Dialogflow my training section doesn't function as it used to. As you can see in the picture, it says that there's no match. In the history I see that the intent has been matched and the correct answer has been given. When I click to assign an intent in the training section, it doesn't save properly.

[image]

As a result of this, I haven't been able to train the conversations with our chatbot. I've already contacted Google Support, but they're still waiting on their engineering team. Hopefully one of you guys can help me out!